# CK Editor styles not working

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter, ckeditor

I am using CK Editor 4.5 as text editor in my form.
I have pasted my html code including "style" tags to the editor. But when saving the data it automatically removes the style tags from the code.

I have tried to turn off Automatic Content Filtering by add this to config file

```
config.allowedContent = true;
```

But it still remove the style tags. The editor also removes the text color, text align styles added.

How can i add style tags using CK Editor.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My apologies. Its not the issue of ckeditor.

I am using codeigniter for server scripts. It removes inline style on form submit.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Rails and met the same issue, it turns out that I'm using `sanitize` to render content, which will remove the inline styles.